# pdf with custom fields in my module prestashop 1.6

Tags: pdf, module, prestashop-1.6

In a module that I create I want to generate a PDF with custom fields to pick from a form in prestashop 1.6.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED!
I use directly tcpdf because the PDF class prestashop got nothing.
In every way if anyone knows how to do with the kind of prestashop I would like to know how to use it.